# Autoloading multiple PHP projects via composer

Tags: php, composer-php, spl-autoload-register, psr-0

Assume I have folder layout as

```
projectA
projectA\src
projectA\vendor\autoload.php

projectB
projectB\src
projectB\vendor\autoload.php

projectC
projectC\src
projectC\vendor\autoload.php
```

These projects need to be in the same level and they need to coexist with each others, e.g. `projectA` might use codes from `projectB` and `projectC` and vice vera, so they cannot be placed into the `vendor` folder.

The thing is: the `autoload.php` in each project is able to autoload their own `src` and `vendor` folder, but how to autoload for the others as well?

Assume their neighbor's project will have the folder name as the PHP namespace, is it possible to setup a autoload.php (via composer) such that in the future when I add new project folder, the autoload will magically work?

Comment: `so they cannot be placed into the vendor folder.` - err, why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can write in each project a composer.json with custom autoload configuration.. 
examples:

ProjectA:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "ProjectB\\": "path/ProjectB/src/",
        "ProjectC\\": "path/ProjectC/src/"
    }
},
```

ProjectB:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "ProjectA\\": "path/ProjectA/src/",
        "ProjectC\\": "path/ProjectC/src/"
    }
},
```

Composer is conceived for manage dependencies of single project.. Load more autoload.php of different projects is not a good idea..
but with this method you can create a complete autoloader for each projects

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to do what's been asked - it would be more logical to simply treat project a/b/c as normal dependencies (that does mean each project has a _standalone_ copy of the other two projects in the vendor folder). I've done what is described here before, and it's a short path to instability such as updating one project causing all projects to fail immediately. +1 for the direct answer though.

Comment: Yes this isn't a good practive but this method resolve question.. is a good pratice manage each project indipendendently from others..